# Monotonicity preserving multivariate interpolation

Tags: interpolation, monotone-functions

Let $f: X \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a strictly component-wise monotone function on the compact (but not convex) set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

I would like to interpolate $f$ on $X$, preserving the component-wise monotonicity, assuming I can only evaluate the function $f$ on a set of discrete points $C = \{x_i \in X\}$ that do not form a regular grid.

In one dimension, I know that the [Monotone Cubic Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation), as well as linear interpolation would fulfill my requirements. As I do not have a regular grid, I cannot use repeated univariate interpolation.

Is there a multivariate interpolation method that preserves component-wise monotonicity and does not need a regular grid?
Would [Polyharmonic Splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyharmonic_spline) work for this (either in general, or for k=1)?

Comment: What does _monotonicity_ even mean in the $\mathbb R^n$ case?  Coordinate-wise monotonicity?

Comment: You're right, monotonicity unclear in $\mathbb{R}^n$. But yes, coordinate-wise monotonicity is what I'm looking for, I think. I'll update the question.